# How to authorize user in Cordova app with web token?

Tags: android, cordova

I am developing Cordova app communicating with some server API. I want authorize users with web tokens instead of cookies as I understood this is more secure.
I also understood that I need to encrypt users' info in the token and pass to server somehow (& decrypt?)... What is the correct & secure way to pass web tokens to server from Cordova app?
It is very essential for me to build high level security.

Answer (score 0):

Then implement oauth2 flow over SSL connection.